# how to get name of dynamically generated text input in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to make a page like this

http://agprotective.com.au/invoice/invoice.htm

There someone can add multiple date,site,start time, end time, hours amount by click the button + or can remove the row using - sign button. How can I get the value of that input in php? Normarlly we use `$_POST['here-is-the-value-of-name-attribute-of-the-input-tag'];`

But in the case http://agprotective.com.au/invoice/invoice.htm , I do not know what will be the value of the name attribute of the  tag.

Can anyone tell me how to get the values of the dynamically generated (button generated) input tags and then send them to database.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is simple:

```
<input name="myinput[]" />
```

PHP will then have:

```
$_POST['myinput'][0], $_POST['myinput'][1]...
```

The page you linked does it in a stupid manner, if I'm honest.

Comment: -1 for being disrepectful +1 for being a correct answer nonetheless = 0

Comment: but in my case there could be multiple inputs and how i will now the number ?

Comment: `count($_POST['myinput'])`